# tts or some other notification sounds not playing at right time when screen is off

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, screen, text-to-speech

tts stops reading the next paragraph when screen is off , notification sounds from some apps don't play while screen is off.
But when I turn on the screen it starts playing again, even if I don't unlock.

Answer (score -1):

Android suspends its tts service when screen turned off.